# Return most common values in an array in Cocoa

Tags: arrays, cocoa-touch, collections, counter

Python has a collections library. In my web application I use `collections.Counter(aList).most_common([n])` to return the `n` most common items in `aList`.

Nice, concise, reasonably fast.

Now I'm working on an iOS application. Is there anything in objective-C or the Cocoa frameworks that can give me the same function for an array of strings?

Assume `aList` is an `NSArrary` of `NSStrings`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *aCounter = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[aList count]];
for aString in aList {
    NSUInteger keyCount = [aCounter valueForKey:aString];
    if keyCount == nil {
        [aCounter setValue:1 forKey:aString];
    }
    else {
        [aCounter setValue:(keyCount+1) forKey:aString];
    }
```

Any suggestions for condensing this or improving its performance?

Answer (score 0):

On my phone, but this should get you half way there:

```
NSArray *input = ...
NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:input];
NSMutableDictionary *output = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (id elem in set) [output setObject:[set countForObject:elem] forValue:elem];
```

If this isn't fast enough, I would look at optimizing at insertion time.